# Schedule Dashboard Refresh with a Dynamic Dashboard

Tags: dashboard, dynamic, refresh

How to schedule a dynamic dashboard refresh.

Requirement:
1.  While communities allow portal users to view Dashboards, Salesforce doesn’t allow community users to refresh/schedule dashboards. 
Our org has hundreds of community customers and it’s not practical to create one dashboard for every customer - so they created a dynamic dashboard “Case Dashboard”. However Salesforce also does not allow dynamic dashboards to be scheduled for a refresh - even by admins.

2. Allow automatic refresh of “Case Dashboard” when a portal user runs that dashboard or goes to the dashboard page.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think we might be able to schedule dynamic dashboards. I just wrote an article on it and shared my findings -

https://cloudyaffair.wordpress.com/2015/07/22/bulk-scheduling-dashboard-refresh/

Answer (score 0):

You can't schedule refreshes for dynamic dashboards. They must be refreshed manually.